# Expected Value of Recurrences for a Random Terminating Process

Tags: probability

I have a fairly advanced mathematical education, but only rudimentary probability theory, and I'm wondering about expectation values for a certain kind of process. Specifically, I'm playing [Idlefall](http://www.kongregate.com/games/truefire/idlefall?haref=HP_HNG_idlefall), a fairly simple Flash game wherein blocks fall onto a row of paddles. One of the upgradeable attributes is the probability that a given block will bounce off the paddle (where, if a bounce fails, the block is 'absorbed' and disappears). This sets up what should be a fairly simple probability problem:

If a block bounces with probability P, and will bounce consecutively until it disappears, what is the expected number of bounces for the block?

My initial heuristics say that a bounce probability of 0.5 results in a single expected bounce, and to note that a probability of 1 results in an infinite number of bounces. At first I thought that the bounces were independent of one another, and so I took the expected number of bounces to be ln(0.5)/ln(P), since  0.5 is my heuristic threshold for expecting a bounce to succeed. However I think this solution may be a bit too glib and a bit unsatisfying, since the bounces are really not independent at all (since bounce N only occurs if bounce N-1 did, and so forth).

As I said, I expect this problem is rather simple, though likely a bit more complicated than my current analysis suggests. Does anyone else have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected number of bounces can be modeled with the recursion $E = P \cdot (1 + E) + (1-P) \cdot 0$, or just $E = \frac{P}{1-P}$.

In other words, at each stage of the recursion, there is a probability $P$ that we get one bounce and then start the process over again, and a probability $1-P$ that the bounce fails and no additional bounces are counted.

Comment: Thank you! This would be even better if the model had an explanation, though.

Comment: Added some more detail.

Comment: Another way to view it: $~$ You are counting bounces before absorption in an indefinite sequence of drops, where each drop has an independent probability $P$ of bouncing (thus becoming the next drop). $~$ This is a (Zero-Shifted) **Geometric Distributed** Random Variable : $X\sim\mathcal {Geo}_0(1-P)$ and $\mathsf E(X)=\frac{P}{1-P}$ . $~$ A classic way to prove the mean of such a variable is exactly as done.